# How to get rid of horizontal background bar in scroll view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, xcode5

I am making an app that has three pages that you can swipe through. I made the scroll view the correct size on the screen, however there is a solid bar of the blue background color across the top. How do I get rid of this? My code and a link to an image is posted below.

[Click Here for Image](http://imgur.com/cJYEGJk)

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3,
                                        self.scrollView.frame.size.height-64);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    int i = 0;
    while (i<=2) {

        UIView *views = [[UIView alloc]
                         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((self.scrollView.frame.size.width)*i)+2, 0,
                                                  (self.scrollView.frame.size.width)-3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        views.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [views setTag:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:views];

        i++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line where you set the background color on your scrollView:

```
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Change that color, or remove the line, and the blue color will change. Other than that, it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish, so maybe some frame corrections might be necessary as well.

EDIT: Along the storyboard fix, here's the tweaked code:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - 64);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake((self.scrollView.frame.size.width) * i, 0,
                                  (self.scrollView.frame.size.width), self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:i * 0.3 green:0.75 blue:0.75 alpha:1.0];

        [view setTag:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming he set that color to see where his views are. His problem  probably is an offset of the content.

Comment: @Adis Yes, I updated the image to better show the problem, there is a blue bar at the top that I would like to get rid of.

Comment: What happens when you remove the -64px from the contentSize in the first line?

Comment: @Adis The blue bar still appears, but after I click it dissapears under the navigation bar, but then there is a scroll bar.

Comment: @Adis Would you like a download link to the project?

Comment: Sure, I can check it out.

Comment: Alright, your issue was in the way your scrollView was set up in the storyboard, it was slightly moved down, and the navigationBar was ambiguous. I set the frame correctly in the storyboard, set the navBar, and tweaked your code a bit (see the edit in the answer):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13129080/Archive.zip

Comment: Also, you'll want to add some autolayout constraints to your views to make sure they scale properly on different screen sizes.

Comment: @Adis I know this is a pretty dumb question but how would I go about adding autolayout constraints to the views?

Comment: That's a wide topic, but I suggest you start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html and here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1